# Golang calls the return value of the cmd when the cmd is invoked

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "/t.py")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()
    select {

    }
}
```

---

t.py

```
while True:
    print("22222")
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

It will not output at any time, python program must exit, or golang will exit?

**I expect golang to call CMD to execute Python program and get the return value of CMD at all times.**
It should be the problem of line buffer。

When I use Python call, there is no line buffer problem.

```
import os

r1, w1 = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()

if pid:
    print("p")
    r1 = os.fdopen(r1)
    while 1:
        str = r1.read(1)
        print(str, end="")
else:
    os.dup2(w1, 1)
    os.dup2(w1, 2)
    os.execve("/Users/hulingjie/.env1/bin/python", ["python", "/t.py"], os.environ.copy())
```

Comment: `cmd.Run()` contains the error status from the call, so youd probably want to define the `StdoutPipe`

Comment: Also, you should probably set the correct path for the command

Comment: An example from the documentation: https://play.golang.org/p/XzRbRcDEbvH

Comment: was your file really in `/t.py` (root directory), i think you need to change it to `./t.py` or else change it to absolute path like this `/home/neo/t.py` or something similar

Comment: No error in running the program     I mean, because "Linux line buffered" has no return value.

Comment: Your program will work as described, provided you import `time`. Please create a [mcve] demonstrating the precise problem you're having.